# Как удалить объект из массива (checked, unchecked) rest api fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

При клике(чеке) я вызываю массив объектов и записываю в массив, а теперь при (анчеке) нужно удалить эти объекты из массива. Не могу понять где я ошибся, в консоли вызываются те же объекты которые мне нужно удалить. Пробовал так же удалять через delete setCategorySub(result.data);

```
let getDataCategory = async (event) => {
        let id = event.currentTarget.id;

        if (event.target.checked){

        await fetch(`http://api.tmweb.ru/category?filter[parent_id][in]=${id}&filter[type]=0`,{
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': token,
            },
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((result) => {
                    setCategorySub([...categorySub,...result.data]);
            })

        }else{

            await fetch(`http://api.tmweb.ru/category?filter[parent_id][in]=${id}&filter[type]=0`,{
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': token,
                },
            })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then((result) => {
                    console.log(result.data)
                    delete result.data;
                })
        }
    }
```

Comment: Зачем вы при анчеке получаете данные от апи? Вам надо в локальном состоянии найти элементc ID и удалить его.

Comment: @SwaD Так для начала нужно их взять из запроса всё равно, и как они запомнятся если у меня 5-20 элементов каталога?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все полученные данные уже хранятся в состоянии компонент. Необходимо удалить элемент с заданным ID из состояния.

```
const getDataCategory = async (event) => {

  let id = event.currentTarget.id;

  if (event.target.checked) {
    // Тут запрашиваете данные
  } else {
    // Удаляете элемент из состояния
    setCategorySub((prevData) => { //prevData текущее состояние
      return prevData.filter((item) => item.id !== id); // Фильтруем массив и сохраняем как состояние
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: К сожалению не работает, ничего не удаляет.

Comment: если поставить === id то можно удалить все данные, но не те которые надо, а так вообще ничего не удаляется

Comment: Какой формат данных приходит от апи? Возможно id приходит числом, в то время как event.currentTarget.id - это строка.

Comment: Всё понял, просто у меня нужно было не item.id сравнивать, а item.parent_id. Спасибо